# How to display Hello World on a graphing calculator (on a screen)?

Tags: ti-basic

I am trying to make my graphing calculator display `Hello, World!` on the screen. How do I do this (I want to program a program to do this,  as typing `alpha`, `letter` is inefficient)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Text(` command in the draw menu.

Where `X` and `Y` are your locations:
`Text(X, Y, "HELLO, WORLD")`

According to catalog:
`Text(row, column, text1, text2, ..., text n)`

On color calculators the text color can be changed with the `TextColor(` command.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the following code:

`Disp "Hello, World!"`

Answer (score 1):

The best (smallest in bytes, and really close to the fastest) an way to do this on the calculator is to use the following line of code:

```
Disp "HELLO WORLD
```

Because of an interesting quirk with TI-Basic, you do not need to use ending quotes, parentheses, curly braces, or square brackets if they are at the end of a line, or preceding a -> (store arrow).